# Nevron Charts for SSRS - Mixed Label Layouts and Center text

Tags: reporting-services, nevron

I have to build the following chart (rendered in excel):

[image]

Using [Nevron Charts](https://www.nevron.com/products-reporting-services-chart-gallery-charting-types-pie-chart.aspx) for SSRS I have gotten this far:

[image]

**I am not able to center the labels and also unable to mix and match label layouts.**

Notice the sample has spider labels mixed with centered labels (i.e. labels placed on pie sector).
Also, I had to use the following expression to add both the category and value with a new line to the label as follows:
`="<label>" & "<br/>" & "<value>" & "%"`

Since it's still one label, I cannot center it as required.

Any ideas? Hacks are fine too.

Comment: Based on this https://www.nevron.com/Forum/8919/Pie-Chart-Label-Mode, I think, we cannot mix and match label layouts. I would still appreciate help in centering the numbers in the label.

Answer (score 0):

I did a google search and found a link to this article which might be able to answer you question: https://www.nevron.com/Forum/6489/How-to-text-align-in-Pie-chart-data-label

Basically, the user wanted the labels to be center-aligned text and not towards a certain side(left or right). As I think this might work for you here is the code below:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using Nevron.GraphicsCore;
using Nevron.Chart;
using Nevron.ReportingServices;

namespace MyNamespace
{
 /// <summary>
 /// Sample class
 /// </summary>
 public class MyClass
 {
  /// <summary>
  /// Main entry point
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="context"></param>
  public static void RSMain(NRSChartCodeContext context)
  {
   if (context.Document.Charts.Count == 0)
    return;
    
   NChart chart = context.Document.Charts[0];
   
   NPieSeries pieSeries = chart.Series[0] as NPieSeries;
   
   if (pieSeries != null)
   {
    pieSeries.AutomaticLabelAlignment = false;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Hopefully this works for you!